# Power Circuit to Subtract a Voltage by a Known Amount

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, charge-pump, negative-voltage

Using a charge-pump it's possible to *add* voltages together (i.e. *source* 10V + *PWM* 5V = 15V, ignoring diode drops)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faqIS1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Surely there must be a way to **subtract** voltages using a similar technique (i.e. 10V - 5V = 5V)?

I know subtracting voltages can be done with OpAmps, but I'm specifically looking to do this and draw a measurable amount of power from the output (> 50mA).  The best solution I could conjure to date involves a transformer.

Comment: Modulating a signal onto a supply rail through a capacitor is rather different from adding two power sources together. Those are not comparable.

Answer (score 3):

> I know subtracting voltages can be done with OpAmps, but I'm specifically looking to do this and draw a measurable amount of power from the output (> 50mA). The best solution I could conjure to date involves a transformer.

Yet you're so close with the opamp:

Imagine this: you've got a component that acts as a resistor, but is always automatically set to a resistance that leads to exactly the voltage drop you want.

If you *know* the voltage from which you're subtracting (e.g. it's always 10V), then a simple linear (positive) voltage regulator would do.

You can build such a dedicated voltage dropper (it's simply a linear regulator, by the way, but not in its most common positive-voltage-relative-to-ground variant).

Something like (doing this from the top of my head, so add additional components for stabilization and what not if this doesn't perform well enough):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuNP2l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>